# Extract SOAP Method from HttpRequest object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a logging method that gets called every time a WebService is called and is used to log information about the call. I need to be able to extract the Service Method name that was called for logging purposes.

How can I do this with just the HttpRequest object passed into the logging function?

```
   public static void LogApiCall(HttpRequest  httpRequest, string resultText = "Success", int resultCode = 0)
   {
      // Need to get the SOAP method named called from httpRequest here...
   }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code I ended up using from the accepted answer (slightly modified). This code was tested and verified to work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the Soap method name called from the http request object.
/// </summary>
public static string SoapMethod(HttpRequest httpRequest)
{

    var bodyRequest = XDocument.Parse(GetDocumentContents(httpRequest));

    if (bodyRequest.Root == null) 
        return httpRequest.Url.AbsoluteUri; 

    var element = bodyRequest.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Body").Elements().FirstOrDefault();

    return element != null ? element.Name.LocalName : httpRequest.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the input stream to a string for XML parsing.
/// </summary>
private static string GetDocumentContents(HttpRequest request)
{
    string documentContents;

    request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    using (var receiveStream = request.InputStream)
    {
        using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return documentContents;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the url of the httpRequest contain the service method name affixed at the end?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's not. The method name is embedded in the SOAP header. The url only has the ASMX file name.

Comment: Check: http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2002/11/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void LogApiCall(HttpRequest httpRequest, string resultText = "Success", int resultCode = 0)
{

    XDocument bodyRequest = XDocument.Parse(GetDocumentContents(httpRequest));
    string methodName = bodyRequest.Root
                                    .Elements()
                                    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Body")
                                    .Elements()
                                    .FirstOrDefault().Name.LocalName;
}

private static string GetDocumentContents(HttpRequest request)
{
    string documentContents;
    using (Stream receiveStream = request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return documentContents;
}
```